# Sorting comment and reply based on parent value in array list (nested comments)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a list with comments and replies. if a comment is a reply it is identity with parent value. I want comments to be on top of replies.(I want nested comments)
This is my list:

```
    sortedComment.add(CommentTest(id=1, parent=0))
    sortedComment.add(CommentTest(id=2, parent=0))
    sortedComment.add(CommentTest(id=3, parent=0))
    sortedComment.add(CommentTest(id=4, parent=1))
    sortedComment.add(CommentTest(id=5, parent=2))
    sortedComment.add(CommentTest(id=6, parent=3))
    sortedComment.add(CommentTest(id=7, parent=6))
    sortedComment.add(CommentTest(id=8, parent=6))
    sortedComment.add(CommentTest(id=9, parent=2))
    sortedComment.add(CommentTest(id=10, parent=5))
    sortedComment.add(CommentTest(id=11, parent=5))
    sortedComment.add(CommentTest(id=12, parent=13))
    sortedComment.add(CommentTest(id=13, parent=4))
```

I want to sort them like this:

```
    1 -> comment
    4 --> replay for 1
    13 --> replay for 4
    12 --> replay for 13
    2 -> comment
    9 --> replay for 2
    5 --> replay for 2
    10 -->replay for 5
    11 --> replay for 5
    3 -> comment
    6 --> replay for 3
    7 --> replay for 6
    8 --> replay for 6
```

I already have some solution but it does not work. These are my solutions:

solution 1:

```
    var index = -1
    var replyIndex: Int
    sortedComment.forEach { comment ->
        replyIndex = -1
        index++
        if (comment.parent != 0) {
            sortedComment.forEach { reply ->
                replyIndex++
                if (comment.parent == reply.id) {
                        Collections.swap(sortedComment, index, replyIndex+1 )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

solution 2:

```
        for (comment in sortedComment){
        if (sortedComment2.size==sortedComment.size) break
        if (comment.parent==0)
            sortedComment2.add(comment)
            sortedComment.forEach { reply->
            if (comment.id==reply.parent){
                sortedComment2.add(reply)
                sortedComment.forEach {cg->
                    if (reply.id==cg.parent)
                        sortedComment2.add(cg)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would be really grateful if anyone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is something as follows:

```
ArrayList <CommentTest> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < sortedComment.size(); i++) {
    CommentTest comment = sortedComment.get(i);
    if(comment.getParent() == 0) {
      sortedList.add(comment);
      LinkedList<Integer> to_search = new LinkedList<Integer>();
      to_search.addFirst(comment.getId());
      while(!to_search.isEmpty()){
          for(int j = i + 1; j < sortedComment.size(); j++) {
              CommentTest c = sortedComment.get(j);
              if(c.getParent() == to_search.getFirst()) {
                 sortedList.add(c);
                 to_search.addLast(c.getId());
               }
          }
          to_search.removeFirst();
      }
    }
}
```

The logic that I have followed was: first we start by adding the comment (I am assuming that they will come first). Let us say id=**1**, then we search for the parent that matches that `id`,  *i.e.,* id=?, parent=**1**.

When we find the replay who's parent matches the ID of the current replay/comment (*i.e.,* `c.getParent() == to_search.getFirst()`), we added it to the sorted list (*i.e.,* `sortedList.add(c);`). Then we repeat the same process, but this time for that parent that we just found. Hence, why I added that parent `id` to the list of elements to search  (*i.e.,* `to_search.addLast(c.getId());`). After having completed a search I remove that element from the top of the stack `to_search.removeFirst();`.

The entire search of replay of a replay ... to a comment stops when there are no more elements on the stack to search  `while(!to_search.isEmpty())`.

All this logic is because I wanted to make sure that after a certain comment all its replies come first, for instance:

```
 2 -> comment
 9 --> replay for 2
 5 --> replay for 2
```

and not some replay of a replay fist. However, if that is not a hard constraint for the sorting criteria that you are using, and a sorting like this : `1 4 13 12 2 5 10 11 9 3 6 7 8` is a valid one. Then we can simplify the code for something much simpler such as:

```
void sort_comments(List <CommentTest> unsorted, List <CommentTest> sorted, int parentID){
    for (CommentTest c :  unsorted){
         if (c.getParent() == parentID){
             sorted.add(c);
             sort_comments(unsorted, sorted, c.getId());
         }
    }
}
```

Or even more elegant with using streams :

```
void sort_comments(List <CommentTest> unsorted, List<CommentTest> sorted, int parentID){
  unsorted.stream().filter(c -> c.getParent() == parentID).forEach(c -> { sorted.add(c); 
        sort_comments(unsorted, sorted, c.getId()); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// creates map {parent -> list of children}
// {0=[1, 2, 3], 1=[4], 2=[5, 9], 3=[6], 6=[7, 8], 5=[10, 11], 13=[12], 4=[13]}
val map = sortedComment.groupBy({ it.parent }, { it.id })

// recursively adds the ids of children
// for example if key == 2 it will add 5 from [5, 9] then 10 from [10, 11], 
// then 11, then it will go back to [5, 9] and will take 9 (result [5, 10, 11, 9])
fun helper(key: Int): List<Int> = map[key]?.flatMap { listOf(it) + helper(it) } ?: listOf()

val result = helper(0) // [1, 4, 13, 12, 2, 5, 10, 11, 9, 3, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys. I think i have a batter solution with better performance:

```
private fun sortComment(parentId: String,sortedList:ArrayList<Item>){
    for (comment in unsortedList){
        if (sortedList.size==unsortedList.size) break
        if (comment.parent!=parentId)
            continue
        sortedList.add(comment)
        sortComment(comment.id!!,sortedList)
    }
}
```

For anyone that has same problem with nested comments this is a good solution for sorting them.